# How to delete selected multiple records in a collection in MongoDB using MongoDB compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'm very new to MongoDB and MongoDB Compass.

I have some 1000 records in a customer collection.
How I can delete all the records at once through MongoDB compass.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Do dropping the collection can work for you ?

Answer (score 21):

You can use Embedded Shell provided by the MongoDB compass. Its in beta mode right now. I am using compass version **1.23.0**

[image: MongoDB compass with Shell]

To delete multiple records, you can use `db.<collectionname>.deleteMany`
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/

Answer (score 4):

You can use MONGOSH (terminal) and run the follow commands:

```
>use <your database>

>db.<your collection>.deleteMany({})
```

As a result, all data in your collection will be delete

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have indexes on that collection you can just drop the entire collection as shown in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/collections/#drop-a-collection).

If you have indexes, however, dropping the collection will also delete the indexes, but it is usually much faster to drop the whole thing and then recreate both the collection and the indexes than removing all the documents using remove (`db.collection.remove({})`), as that would have to go document by document freeing up the space they take and removing their entry on the indexes, if any.

The only caveat of this approach is that in a sharded cluster, you might drop a collection and, even if the drop is reported as successful, the collection might still be present in some nodes, causing issues when recreating it.

You can read more about this still `OPEN` issue and its workaround at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17397:

> **ISSUE SUMMARY**
>
> When dropping a database / collection in a sharded cluster, even if the drop is reported as successful it is possible the database / collection may still be present in some nodes in the cluster. At this time, we do not recommend that users drop a database or collection and then attempt to reuse the namespace.
>
> **USER IMPACT**
>
> When the database/collection is not successfully dropped in a given node, the corresponding files continue to use disk space in that node. Attempting to reuse the namespace may lead to undefined behavior.
>
> **WORKAROUNDS**
>
> To work around this issue one can follow the steps below to drop a database/collection in a sharded environment:
>
> 1. Drop the database / collection using a `mongos`.
> 2. Connect to each shard's primary and verify the namespace has been dropped. If it has not, please drop it. Dropping a database (e.g `db.dropDatabase()`) removes the data files on disk for the database being dropped.
> 3. Connect to a `mongos`, switch to the `config` database and remove any reference to the removed namespace from the collections `chunks`, `locks`, `databases` and `collections`:
>
>    **When dropping a database:**
>
>    ```
>    use config
>    db.collections.remove( { _id: /^DATABASE\./ } )
>    db.databases.remove( { _id: "DATABASE" } )
>    db.chunks.remove( { ns: /^DATABASE\./ } )
>    db.locks.remove( { _id: /^DATABASE\./ } )
>    ```
>
>    **When dropping a collection:**
>
>    ```
>    use config
>    db.collections.remove( { _id: "DATABASE.COLLECTION" } )
>    db.chunks.remove( { ns: "DATABASE.COLLECTION" } )
>    db.locks.remove( { _id: "DATABASE.COLLECTION" } )
>    ```
> 4. Connect to each `mongos` and run [`flushRouterConfig`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/flushRouterConfig/).

Comment: Is this answer related to deleting records in MongoDB Compass? Because that is what OP wants. How to apply db.collection.remove({}) in MongoDB Compass?

Comment: Yes, if you check the [first link](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/collections/#drop-a-collection), it mentions how to drop a whole collection using MongoDB Compass. I'm mentioning the issue with dropping a collection on sharded clusters because in that case, it would be better to use the other approach or the workaround using the shell, as there's no way to do `db.collection.remove({})` on MongoDB Compass other than manually deleting document by document, which is not doable on big collections.