# Does Mongo Compass include Delete many documents at one time function?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using `MongoDB` for a while with my projects. But Um currently New to `MongoDB` compass application. so When I want to delete a lot of documents at a time .
How will I perform that operation in `Mongo Compass` ?

Answer (score 12):

Latest stable version of Compass (1.16.3) does not support a delete many operation.
To do that, you need to use the mongo shell - 
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/remove-documents/

Comment: The links seems to be outdated. Answer by @MuhammadTariq provides a good tutorial.

Answer (score 8):

While searching for shell option with MongoDB Compass, I come to know that compass also provides built-in shell which can be used to execute MongoDB commands. Please check my answer below for more information.

[How to delete selected multiple records in a collection in MongoDB using MongoDB compass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448957/how-to-delete-selected-multiple-records-in-a-collection-in-mongodb-using-mongodb/65073905#65073905)

Cheers,

Answer (score 6):

A workaround in Compass, drop the collection first and then create the collection with the same name, or even import some sample document.

Comment: This does not answer the question.
Dropping a collection would remove all data in the collection. The OP want to know how to delete some data in the collection not all.

Comment: I agree that this doesn't answer the original question but this suggestion is perfect for my case. I am in testing phase and I need to continuously delete data in collections and drop + recreate method works for me. Because its NoSql, so no need to create column and data types. I am from SQL background and here I can feel the NoSql power.

Answer (score 5):

The only way [until release 1.20.5], is to execute the delete command from mongo-shell.
Here are the steps and example to delete multiple documents matching a filter, using a mongo-shell

1. download mongo-shell from the [link](https://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-shell-win32-x86_64-2012plus-4.2.3.zip)
2. Open the command-prompt and navigate to the folder where binary files are present
3. Connect to mongo-server, Run the connection command > `mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster-name.mongodb.net/db_name"  --username <uasername> --password <password>`
4. example delete command, run : `db.users.remove( { status : "P" } )` to remove all documents from the users collection where the status field equals "P"

Answer (score 3):

I use [Robo 3T delete function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVFNC.png) to delete many records, because in MongoDB Compass you can only do it one by one.

Comment: Unfortunately Robo 3T is not able to execute update or delete functions on Windows 11. Is there any fixed version of Robo 3T that works on Windows 11?

Comment: Hello instead of Robo 3T you can use Navicat in Windows 11 (also available for MongoDB) to do the operations you need.